# Django mptt tutorial error

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-mptt

I was following [this tutorial](http://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/tutorial.html#getting-started) and i got stuck.

I have defined everything as mentioned in the tutorial but i am getting the following error:

```
NameError at /genres/
global name 'Genre' is not defined
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/genres/
Django Version: 1.6.2
Exception Type: NameError
Exception Value:    
global name 'Genre' is not defined
Exception Location: /home/abhishek/projects/mptt/mpttsample/mpttmodel/views.py in show_genres, line 4
Python Executable:  /home/abhishek/projects/mptt/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
Python Path:    
['/home/abhishek/projects/mptt/mpttsample',
 '/home/abhishek/projects/mptt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_mptt-0.6.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/abhishek/projects/mptt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_mptt-0.6.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/abhishek/projects/mptt/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/abhishek/projects/mptt/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/home/abhishek/projects/mptt/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/abhishek/projects/mptt/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/abhishek/projects/mptt/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/abhishek/projects/mptt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/abhishek/projects/mptt/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 18 Mar 2014 11:07:13 -0500
```

Please let me know my mistake. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to say because you haven't posted any sample code, but python will give the `global name 'variable' is not defined` statement when this variable is not defined in the current namespace.

If you are working directly from the tutorial, and the error is thrown in `views.py`, my guess is that you forgot to import the model in this file.

Try:

```
from mttp.models import Genre
```

where `mttp` is the name of your app. I just grabbed this from the tutorial site but you may or may not have it set up differently.